# use strict in javascript not working for fat arrow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, use-strict

I found an interesting case where "use strict" is not working as expected in javascript.
Following functions

```
"use strict";

var y = () => {
    console.log(this);
}

var x = function () {
    console.log(this);
}

x(); // undefined due to use strict
y(); // window object
```

I think fat arrow context should also be overwritten by undefined, or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Since you are executing this in the global scope (where `this` is the `window` object), and `this` in arrow functions is lexical, I don't see what's unexpected about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MDN says of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Relation_with_strict_mode):

> **Relation with strict mode**
>
> Given that `this` is lexical, strict mode rules with regard to `this` are just ignored.
>
> ```
> var f = () => {'use strict'; return this};
> f() === window; // or the global object
> ```

The rules of lexical `this` take precedence over strict-mode `this` rules.

We can see this easily in the ES2015 specification by examining the plain-English description of possible values for [a function's `[[ThisMode]]` slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects), which can be `lexical`, `strict`, or `global`:

> Defines how `this` references are interpreted within the formal parameters and code body of the function. `lexical` means that `this` refers to the `this` value of a lexically enclosing function. `strict` means that the `this` value is used exactly as provided by an invocation of the function. `global` means that a `this` value of `undefined` is interpreted as a reference to the global object.

In other words, a function's `this` behavior can either be strict, non-strict, or lexical. If a function's `[[ThisMode]]` is lexical (as it is for an arrow function), it renders the function's strict/non-strict status irrelevant for the purpose of determining `this`-setting behavior.