# How to determine the correct `this` inside a regular arrow fn with "strict" and "non-strict" mode?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this, arrow-functions

For the below code snippet

### Case 1: Strict mode

```
"use strict"

let obj = {
  method: function(){
    console.log(this);
  },
  arrowMethod: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

obj.method(); // call 1
obj.arrowMethod(); // call 2

let method = obj.method;
let arrowMethod = obj.arrowMethod;

method(); // call 3
arrowMethod(); // call 4
```

The output is:

```
{method: ƒ, arrowMethod: ƒ}
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
undefined
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
```

### Case 2: Non-Strict mode

Same snippet will output

```
{method: ƒ, arrowMethod: ƒ}
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
```

My understanding is that:

In the strict mode,

- `call 1` - When a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on.
- `call 2` - No matter what, arrowMethod's this is set to what it was when it was created (in the example above, the global object).
- `call 3` - If the value of this is not set when entering an execution context, it remains undefined.
- `call 4` No matter what, arrowMethod's this is set to what it was when it was created (in the example above, the global object).

In the non-strict mode,

- `call 1` - When a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on.
- `call 2` - No matter what, arrowMethod's this is set to what it was when it was created (in the example above, the global object).
- `call 3` - Since the code is not in strict mode, and because the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object, which is a window in a browser.
- `call 4` - No matter what, arrowMethod's this is set to what it was when it was created (in the example above, the global object).

### Question

- Isn't like for `call 4` in `Case 1: Strict mode`, as the value of this is not set when an arrow fn is created, it remains undefined all the time?

  > or
- Is it like strict mode doesn't apply to arrow fns, hence at the time of creation of arrow fn, this is set to window object?

Comment: This question has been answered here already - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427989/8130690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rule for strict mode functions not defaulting from `undefined` to the global object doesn't apply to arrow functions, since they don't have their own `this` at all. It always is the `this` value from the outer scope. And that's `window` in your example.

What might matter is whether the function they are defined in uses strict mode or not, as that's where the arrow function gets its value from:

```js
 function strictMake() {
     "use strict";
     return () => { console.log(this == window); };
 }
 function sloppyMake() {
     return () => { console.log(this == window); };
 }

 const arrowFromStrict = strictMake();
 const arrowFromSloppy = sloppyMake();

 arrowFromStrict();
 arrowFromSloppy();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bergi. This explanation made by day.